# div and textboxes are not aligning at same position when text change

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu

Few hour ago I have asked question that for to align 2 text boxes in line.

But now problem is text boxes are aligned and I have put select list in side of each text box.

but problem is that when I change the label or text before text box all formation disturbed and it's not aligning in same format.
I want that whatever the text I write before text box, the position of text box should not change. (ONE TEXT BOX SHOULD BE AT SAME POSITION UNDER ANOTHER ONE)

[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/u7aTD/1/)

code :

```
.divkl {
    display: inline;
    margin: 20px;
}
.blockl{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding:3px;
}
.txt_prd_add
{
    width:100px;
    border-radius:0px !important;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:4px;
}
.select_prd
{
    width:85px;
    margin-top:4px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zV5JX/)

```
<label class="title">Material</label>

.title {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Yes working. I have tried width to 40 and all adjust. I ll change with as per my need and page.

Comment: @Anup the actual tag `label` would be semantically correct.  If your willing to revise I'm willing to upvote.

Comment: @KevinBowersox If the `label` is used some where else in the page then it will affect that label unnecessarily...!

Comment: @Anup Good point.  I guess that means the label should be qualified appropriately with a selector `label.title`.  If you make those edits you truly have the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap all of the labels in `<label></label>` and then apply a fixed width and `display: inline-block` to the `label` via CSS.  If you want to prevent the elements from wrapping when the browser is resized add `white-space: nowrap;` to `.block1` and `.divk1`

**HTML**

```
<div class="blockl">
    <div class="divkl">
        <label>Material</label>
        <input type="text" class="txt_prd_add">
        <select class="select_prd">
            <option>GB</option>
            <option>MB</option>
            <option>GHz</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="divkl">
        <label>Color</label>
        <input type="text" class="txt_prd_add">
        <select class="select_prd">
            <option>GB</option>
            <option>MB</option>
            <option>GHz</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="blockl">
    <div class="divkl">
        <label>Size</label>
        <input type="text" class="txt_prd_add">
        <select class="select_prd">
            <option>GB</option>
            <option>MB</option>
            <option>GHz</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="divkl">
        <label>Type</label>
        <input type="text" class="txt_prd_add">
        <select class="select_prd">
            <option>GB</option>
            <option>MB</option>
            <option>GHz</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
label{
    width: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.divkl {
    display: inline;
margin: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap; /* Prevents wrapping */
}

.blockl{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding:3px;
    white-space: nowrap; /* Prevents wrapping */
```

}

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/u7aTD/7/

Comment: Your Fiddle looks Awesome!

Comment: @Pavan Thanks, I updated it to prevent wrapping as OP has elluded to.

Answer (score 1):

*Demo*: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/u7aTD/6/

You would better wrap your text in `label`s, e.g.:

```
<div class="divkl">
    <label>Material</label>
    <input type="text" class="txt_prd_add">
    ...
```

And, then apply css to the `label`s, e.g.:

```
label { display: inline-block; width: 10%; }
.txt_prd_add { width:10%; ...
.select_prd { width:10%; ...
```

The problem you are having is with the widths. It would be better if you first apply widths in percentages to check it out, and then tweak it according to your design.

Comment: the example doesn't work as expected. drop down list are not coming on side of text box.

Comment: @user3145373: please specify what exactly are you expecting

Comment: one label then textbox and then drop down and again label then text box then drop down and like this 2-2 controls in each row.

Comment: @user3145373: as i see from here, they are. which browser?

Comment: @abhitalks its the size of the browser window, they are wrapping

Comment: @abhitalks Kind of picky but if you resize the browser window to a very small dimension wrapping still occurs. Look at `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: @KevinBowersox: yes. thank you indeed. i just did a quick fiddle to help the Op understand and left out subtleties. but, yes thanks for taking time out to point that out to me. much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tables insted of divs , as to get proper aling.`
                                        
                                        
                                        Material
                                        
                                            
                                            
                                                GB
                                                MB
                                                GHz
                                            
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        Color
                                        
                                            
                                            
                                                GB
                                                MB
                                                GHz

```
                                    <tr class="divkl"><td>Size</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="txt_prd_add">
                                        <select class="select_prd">
                                            <option>GB</option>
                                            <option>MB</option>
                                            <option>GHz</option>
                                        </select>
                                      </td>  
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="divkl">
                                    <td>Type</td>
                                        <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="txt_prd_add">
                                        <select class="select_prd">
                                            <option>GB</option>
                                            <option>MB</option>
                                            <option>GHz</option>
                                        </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                        </div>`
```